# Starting a Java process from a C++ process

Tags: java, c++, process

How can I start a Java application from within a C++ process?

I don't want to invoke just some parts of the Java application, as could be done with JNI, but actually run the whole Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can follow the steps at this link:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html

Note that the sample invokes the "main" method of the loaded class so it would be just as if you did something like java -jar app.jar where the manifest in app jar specifies a main class that loads and starts the app.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, easily:

```
system("java ClassName");
```

You can certainly get fancier than that, adding environment variables for `CLASSPATH` or whatever else you need. The details of doing so may be moderately system dependent, however.

Answer (score 1):

would  `system("your java command")` work?